# PHP: feof miss last word

Tags: php, eof, feof

the problem is simple but complicated at the same time.
feof doesn't print my last word. It take from file name city and code (Venice,A908) and should show in OUTPUT: nameCity,codeOfCity.
Let me show you an example:

City.csv

```
Abano Terme,A001
Abbadia Cerreto,A004
Abbadia Lariana,A005
Abbiategrasso,A010
Zubiena,M196
Zuccarello,M197
Zuclo,M198
Zungri,M204
```

Code:

```
<?php
$buffer = "";
$file = fopen("City.csv", "r");

//while (($c = fgetc($file)) != EOF )
//while (($c = fgetc($file)) != NULL )
//while (($c = fgetc($file)) !== false )
while(!feof($file)) 
{       
    $c = fgetc($file);
    $buffer .= $c;

    if($c == ",")
    {
        echo $buffer;       
        $buffer = "";
    }

    if($c == "\n")
    {           
        echo $buffer."<br/>";

        $buffer = "";
    }           
}

fclose($file);
?>
```

OUTPUT:

```
Abano Terme,A001 
Abbadia Cerreto,A004 
Abbadia Lariana,A005 
Abbiategrasso,A010 
Zubiena,M196 
Zuccarello,M197 
Zuclo,M198 
Zungri,
```

Comment: you're parsing a csv file, why not use `fgetcsv()`?

Comment: Because there is no `"\n"` at the last line, thus none of the if conditions is satisfied.

Comment: cause I want to get name and city, and getc permit this!

Comment: Why not use fgets and just print it line by line.

Comment: Because I need to get nameCity and Code in different variable!
I just trying all methods submitted by you!!! Thanks :D

Comment: @iam-decoder But If I use fgetcsv, how can I use array giving to me?

Comment: `foreach()` or `for()` will both traverse the array and at each point you can move things around. I'll update my answer to get you the array with the `nameCity` and `codeOfCity` array keys

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems like you are just trying to output the file as is, with only change being to substitute HTML line breaks `<br />` instead of new line characters why not simplify things?

```
echo nl2br(file_get_contents('City.csv'), true);
```

Or if you don't want to read the whole file into memory:

```
$file = fopen('City.csv', 'r');
while(!feof($file)) {       
    echo nl2br(fgets($file), true);
}
fclose($file);
```

In one of the comments above you mention that you want the city and city values available as variables (though your code example doesn't seem to indicate this).  If that is the case, try `fgetcsv()` like this:

```
$file = fopen('City.csv', 'r');
while($values = fgetcsv($file)) {
    $city = $values[0];
    $city_code = $values[1];
    echo $city . ',' . $city_code . '<br />';
}
fclose($file);
```

Comment: @user3649959: Look it up!

Comment: It is PHP's new line to BR tag conversion function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Comment: @user3649959 NOw, if you find yourself wanting to actually read in the CSV and placing values for city and and city code available as variables, then you should look at `fgetcsv()`

Comment: Im trying but didnt understand how get value from array :D

Comment: I tried but It did a loop!
EDIT: Sorry my fault, ok it works :D Thanks

Comment: @user3649959 Not sure what you mean.  It is supposed to loop through every line in the file.

Comment: THANKS, now I must go to work, I will see comments when I come back! Bye and thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, there's no newline at the end of your file, so it never hits the last `"\n"` check to output the buffer contents.

to fix this, you just need to put in another check on that conditional. change

```
if($c == "\n")
```

to:

```
if($c == "\n" || feof($file))
```

Here's a much cleaner and more concise version of your code if you'd like to use the correct function for parsing a csv file:

```
<?php
$buffer = array();
$file = fopen("City.csv", "r");
while(!feof($file) && $buffer[] = fgetcsv($file));
fclose($file);
foreach($buffer as $line){
    echo join(',', $line).'<br/>';
}
?>
```